# programmatically code generation in C# using codedom

Tags: c#, codedom

I want to generate code for creating a hash table object and assigning it with a key and a value programmatic . it should be similar to

```
Hashtable ht = new Hashtable();

ht.Add( "key1", "value1" );
ht.Add( "key2", "value2" );
ht.Add( "key3", "value3" );
```

for eg

```
CodeMemberMethod testMethod = new CodeMemberMethod();

        testMethod.Name = "Test" + mi.Name + "_" + intTestCaseCnt;
        testMethod.Attributes = MemberAttributes.Public;.....
```

here it creates a method programmatically now I want to create a hashtable so I am asking how?

Comment: I might be a bit slow but I have no idea what you asking. Can you please rephrase or give some context.

Comment: Can you be more specific please ? Like, what are your inputs (database, file) ? Is this a one shot operation to generate a piece of code  ?

Comment: @uriDium, I hope you're not slow, but if you are, you're not alone...

Comment: using code dom i want to write a code programactic such that my code writes a code and dispaly it in text file

Comment: dont want the entire tool just a piece of code in code dom

Comment: Better question is : are you just trying to generate a piece of code or are you building a code generator ? Using codedom to generate a single piece of code is an overkill !

Comment: I HAVE ACHIEVE THIS FOR ALL BASIC  DATATYPES  LIKE INT FLOAT NOW I NEED IT TO INPLEMENT FOR A HASH TABLE I JUST NEED TO KNOW HOW WILL U DECLARE A HASH TABLE PROGRAMATICALY

Comment: What problem do you have when you try to do the same thing for Hashtable? You don't get good answers here when you ask people to do your job for you.

Comment: And there's no need to shout, you're being rude. Not the way to have answers when you ask a question !

Comment: i was not rude its was a mistake the caps key was on

Comment: i noticed but i thought it was alright

Comment: Don't understand why people are marking this down, it's a fair question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CodeParameterDeclarationExpression hashTableParam =new CodeParameterDeclarationExpression();
hashTableParam.Name = "hastable";

hashTableParam.Type = new CodeTypeReference(typeof(System.Collections.Hashtable));
```

> this what i was looking for thanks for ur efforts

Answer (score 5):

For code generation consider the [Text Template Transformation Toolkit](http://www.olegsych.com/2007/12/text-template-transformation-toolkit/) (T4)

This template...

```
Hashtable ht = new Hashtable();
<#
    foreach (var obj in DataSource)
    {
#>
ht.Add( "<#= obj.Key #>", "<#= obj.Value #>" );
<#
    }
#>
```

...would generate this output...

```
Hashtable ht = new Hashtable();
ht.Add( "key1", "value1" );
ht.Add( "key2", "value2" );
ht.Add( "key3", "value3" );
...
ht.Add( "keyN", "valueN" );
```

Where N is the number of records in your DataSource.

**The best thing is, this is built right into Visual Studio 2008**

I have had good experiences with it

Comment: Sorry if I misunderstood from you initial clear-as-mud question. The Edit isn’t much better either. I give up.

Comment: Apologies, I missed the crucial part of the edit – “using codedom”. Shame this wasn’t there from the start and I could have saved some time.

Comment: even with code dom this is a nice solution. Text transform is a pretty sweet tool.

Answer (score 1):

Where are you stuck? You know how to create a CodeMemberMethod, so you should be able to add statement objects to the CodeMemberMethod.Statements collection. You'll need one statement for the variable declaration, one for the assignment/initialization and one for each "Add"-Call.

BTW: I've used Code DOM in the past, but found that generating code directly with a templating engine is less works and makes the code far more readable. I usually use [StringTemplate](http://www.stringtemplate.org/), and I'm very happy with it.

Answer (score 0):

The two code generators I'm aware of are ...

Codesmith at ... [main site](http://www.codesmithtools.com/), with a [free version](http://www.codesmithtools.com/freeware.aspx)

T4 which is in  Scott Hanselman has a blog post about it [here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/T4TextTemplateTransformationToolkitCodeGenerationBestKeptVisualStudioSecret.aspx)